# Expanded column with scrolling, floating button and fixed rows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been trying to achieve this layout with **flutter** for many hours, but with no luck

[image]

this is what i have so far and it doesn't work

*Important: *The fixed rows will have a dynamic height.*

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
    child: Text('First row'),
    ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(),
                        Container(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text('Button'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          Container(
           child: Center(child: Text('Footer')
    ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

I do not have much more to say. I don't know how many variants I have tried ... any idea is welcome thanks

Answer (score 1):

In flutter we have **app bar** and **navigation bar**, which will not scroll by default and inside you can use columns and rows achieve this type.

```
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(), // top bar
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(), // bottom bar which doesn't scroll at least by default
    body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column()),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( 
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you Mohan! I think the bottomNavigationBar is going to save my life ...

Comment: Happy to Help ☺️ @lecaro

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has a built-in stationary floating button, called a `FloatingActionButton`.  That should take care of your button needs.

As for the central scrolling section, a `ListView` inside an `Expanded` should do the trick.  You shouldn't need shrinkWrap when you're inside an `Expanded` widget, since constraints will be provided to `ListView` from `Expanded` during the layout phase of non-fixed size widgets (such as `ListView`).

Here's a copy/past example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FabColRowPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FAB Row Column'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => print('FAB was pressed'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TopRow(),
          Expanded(child: ScrollingBody()),
          BottomRow(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('TOP ROW'),
    );
  }
}

class BottomRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('BOTTOM ROW'),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollingBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items = List.generate(20, (index) => 'Item #$index');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(items[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Baker!!! Without a doubt I am closer to a solution thanks to you ...

The problem that I have now, is that the last row (footer) will have a changing height ...

and the FloatingActionButton is above that row, when it is not the idea ... I need it to be above the scrolled view ... with a padding I could position it, but I would need it to be a dynamic padding ...  Could you give me an idea please to solve this last

Comment: Do you think it could be a valid solution to use bottomNavigationBar for the last row?

Comment: Indeed, BottomNavigationBar + docked FAB is a common use-case.  Check out the official doc video on FAB which demonstrates this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

why not you used floatingAction button in Scaffold

eg: Scaffold(

```
floatinActionButton:FloatinActionButton(

 child:Icon(Icons.add),),
```

body: Column(

```
    children: [
      Container(
child: Text('First row'),
),
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I think the floatinActionButton is going to be a solution... but I need to manage the position of the button so that it is not above the last row, and as this row the height is dynamic ... at the moment the only full solution that I have is to also use bottomNavigationBar for the footer (thanks to @Mohan Sai Manthri)... but I'm not sure if this it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Use FloatingActionButton:

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            print('press...');
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Hi Jim, I think the floatinActionButton is going to be a solution... but I need to manage the position of the button so that it is not above the last row, and as this row the height is dynamic ... at the moment the only full solution that I have is to also use bottomNavigationBar for the footer (thanks to @Mohan Sai Manthri)... but I'm not sure if this it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Column(
children: [
  Row(........),
  Expanded(child: ListView(children: [....])),
  Row(........),
 ]
)
```

your `Scaffold` body needs to be like this.

Comment: Hi M.M. you have forgotten the floating button, what you propose is more or less the same as I was already using...